# Docker copy to engine example failed 5/6 => ERROR [build-env 5/6] COPY ../engine/examples ./

Tags: c#, docker

This is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ../engine/examples ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WeatherApi.dll"]
```

dotnet build success full but when am using this command for image creating its giving this error

`docker build -t weatherapi .`

My Project Strcuture

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: `docker build -t weatherapi .` is a command to build an image, not an error.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar well am getting this error  => ERROR [build-env 5/6] COPY ../engine/examples ./

Comment: Does it not give you any more information?

Comment: Yeah the error was gone i just have to do this COPY bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/ app/

Comment: Uh, your dockerfile is trying to build your code for you (correct). By copying in your publish folder, you are copying the code you built manually with Visual Studio (incorrect).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar So what to do is this wrong way

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help you. I've asked for more information about the error, but that information hasn't been forthcoming, so there's not a lot I can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244533/discussion-between-asad-and-diplomacynotwar).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar May be next timing before making it Negative just go through the code or forget about it cause we are learners this was my problem # Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it Resolved by using this

```
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

And it worked like a charm